# How do I convert a UTF-8 string to upper case?

Tags: c, utf-8

Is there a portable way to convert a UTF-8 string in C to upper case? If not, what is the Linux way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The portable way of doing it would be to use a Unicode aware library such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). Seems like [`u_strToUpper`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a14740e3b734ffa82205d4762fcacb5e1) might the function you're looking for.

Comment: As a note, ICU will require you to convert UTF-8 -> UTF-16 -> uppercase UTF-16 -> uppercase UTF-8.  (There aren't really other libraries that do this though.)

Answer (score 8):

glib has [`g_utf8_strup()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-strup).

Comment: I’m sure this is the right answer, but for some reason I get `No manual entry for g_utf8_strup` from running `man g_utf8_strup`, this despite how running `nm /opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.a | grep g_utf8_strup` proves that it’s there. That’s really superstupid. FTFSF.

Comment: @tchrist: Stupid is relative; a man page for every glib function would result in 100+MB of man pages

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: seeing how the **uncompressed HTML** version weighs in at 75 MB, I don't trust your estimate that much.

Comment: @ninjalj: The HTML doesn't have as much detail as a man page would.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this is with wchar_t -- if you have a string of wide characters and use towlower/towupper/towctrans with your wide characters (which will work if your locale is set correctly). So you need to take your UTF-8 string, convert it into a wide-character string, and then use these functions that take wchar_t's and then convert back.

This is a giant PITA so you're probably better off using a supported, open-source Unicode library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: No, this is incorrect.  It's impossible to get it to work with German text (for example), because the uppercase version of ß is SS, which is two characters.  This is far from the only example where it breaks, but the most common.

Comment: True, but it's the only version that's even close to correct using posix-standard libraries (plus I blame the Unicode standard which initially specified a 1:1 case mapping between characters).

Comment: @JacobB Full casing gives much better results than the old simpleminded simple casing, and we have known this for many many years now. That’s why languages like Java and Perl provide full casing on their casemapping functions for strings. Do not work codepoint-by-codepoint; it just doesn’t work. You need the whole string.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Since 2008 there is a "real" uppercase ß: ẞ http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F#Unicode

Comment: @drhirsch: Yes, but the Germans don't actually use it as such.  It's used for representing *historical* documents which already use the thing.  If your program renders uppercase "Floß" as "FLOẞ", then the German users would complain that your program is buggy and they would be right.  Besides, ß is far from the only character which becomes multiple characters when upper-cased.